# ¿Qué significa "de corto"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

Yo quiero saber si alguién ha oido "de corto" como modismo. Estoy leyendo *Cuando fui mortal*, un libro por Javier Marias en el que un futbolista hace una famosa maniobra después de que marchita hasta la oscuridad. ¿Qué quiere decir "de corto"? "Soon?"

De  *Cuando fui mortal*:

> Iba mejor vestido, con corbata y abrigo con el cuello subido, había
>   visto más anuncios; fumó un cigarrillo en cada tiempo, delante de sus
>   jefes y de las cámaras.
>   ¿Cuándo te vemos otra vez **de corto**, Kentucky? —le pregunté.

Comment: Tremendo descubrimiento el de [_analecta_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2VXad7K), nunca había oído esta palabra.

Comment: @fedorqui por Arturo Perez Reverte mi autor favorito

Comment: @fedorqui:  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analectas_de_Confucio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El DLE nos lo explica en su entrada *corto*:

> [**corto<sup>1</sup>, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B356ILe%7CB36eFH7)
>   `Del lat. curtus.`
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que tiene menor longitud de la normal o adecuada, o de la que tienen otras de su misma especie. *Las mangas de esta camisa son cortas.*
> 2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que tiene una determinada longitud. *Una barra más corta, menos corta, igual de corta que otra.*
>
> .../...
>
> **de corto**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Con pantalones cortos.
> 2. loc. adv. Con vestido que no llega hasta los pies. *Aún iba vestida de corto.*
> 3. loc. adv. Con chaquetilla corta. *Iba vestido de corto y con sombrero cordobés.*

Como ves, *de corto* indica *con pantalones cortos*. Por tanto, decir *¿cuándo te vemos otra vez de corto?* es expresar *¿cuánto te vemos con pantalones cortos?* Como los pantalones cortos son el atuendo de los futbolistas para jugar un partido, lo que se quiere decir es:

> ¿Cuándo vuelves a jugar a fútbol?

En la prensa deportiva decir *vestirse de corto* es un recurso que se utiliza mucho para hacer referencia a *jugar* a algún deporte, especialmente cuando se vuelve a hacer. Seguro que el escritor Javier Marías, futbolero y madridista confeso, la tiene muy presente. Velo en noticias como:

- Noticia de baloncesto: [Jordan vuelve a vestirse de corto](https://elpais.com/deportes/2001/10/02/actualidad/1002007312_850215.html)
- Una de fútbol: [Matthäus se vuelve a vestir de corto con 57 años para jugar con su primer equipo](http://www.marca.com/futbol/bundesliga/2018/05/13/5af87f7c22601dfc018b45af.html)
- Una sobre programas de radio sobre deportes: [‘Carrusel’ y ‘El Larguero’ se visten de corto](https://elpais.com/deportes/2016/09/09/actualidad/1473409742_216068.html)

Comment: Estoy aplaudiendo con me teclado. Antes de que haya visto el contexto!

Comment: No creo que en el contexto "de corto" se refiera a pantalón corto. Más bien creo que se refiere a "vestir de largo/de corto". Donde "largo" se refiere a ropa formal/de gala y "corto" a informal/de calle.

Comment: @roetnig por la temática del libro y el contexto que nos da el OP, me temo que se refiere a vestir uniforme deportivo.